# Sagemaker Hyperparameter Tuning Job Mechanism

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Does anyone know what's the mechanism behind hyperparameter tuning job in AWS Sagemaker?

In specific, I am trying to do the following:

1. Bring my own container
2. Minimize cross entropy loss (this will be the objective metric of the tuner)

My question is when we define the hyper parameter in `HyperParameterTuner` class, does that get copied into `/opt/ml/input/config/hyperparameters.json`?

If so, should one adjust the training image so that it uses the hyper parameters from `/opt/ml/input/config/hyperparameters.json`?

Edit: I've looked into some sample HPO notebooks that AWS provides and they seem to confuse me more. Sometimes they'd use `argparser` to pass in the HPs. How is that passed into the training code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i finally figured it out and had it wrong all the time.

The file `/opt/ml/input/config/hyperparameters.json` is there. It just has slightly different content compared to a regular training-job. The params to be tuned as well as static params are contained there. As well as the metric-name.

So here is the structure, i hope it helps:

```json
{
    '_tuning_objective_metric': 'your-metric', 
    'dynamic-param1': '0.3', 
    'dynamic-param2': '1',
    'static-param1': 'some-value', 
    'static-paramN': 'another-value'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you bring your own container, you should consider pip installing [SageMaker Training Toolkit](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-training-toolkit). This will allow you to receive hyperparameters as command line arguments to your training script (to be processed with `argparser`). This will save you the need to Read and parse the `/opt/ml/input/config/hyperparameters.json` yourself.

Comment: I am very confused about it. For a normal Sagemaker-Training Job the hyperparameters are written to `/opt/ml/input/config/hyperparameters.json`. But for this Tuning Jobs we have `static` and `dynamic` hyperparameters. And None of them are written to `/opt/ml/input/config/hyperparameters.json`. The file does not exist for me..

Comment: A tuning job, is an engine that a series of training jobs, so at the end it's just a training job. Make sure that you use the SageMaker Training Toolkit, and it should save you from low level details like this json file (you'll receive input from environment variables and command line arguments, instead).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I will try that. However when i look at the implementation here: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-training-toolkit/blob/master/src/sagemaker_training/environment.py i think it will not help. The `read_hyperparameters()` tries to open exactly this `.json` file.